# Google Script transforming colours to HEX codes for 23.000 Rows

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, hex

I have a list of 23.000 Cells (H3:H23003) which all have a specific cell colour. I need the HEX values for those colours. Currently I get those by running this script in the Script Editor:

```
function getHex(input) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var cell = ss.getRange(input);
var result = cell.getBackground();
return result
}
```

And then I use this formula in the sheet:

```
=getHex(cell("address",G21))
```

But due to the large amount of cells it takes ages to copy down the formula and get the HEX value.

Is there a way to do this in an automated process, by either having a script that can run each cell at a time, without me having to copy the formula down manually or calculate the values in the script and just paste the HEX values?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply Epascarello. 

I tried to create a for loop, but I can't get it to work. 

Do you have either good guide for how I could use the for loop or maybe even an idea of how you would write it for the above?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of getting the background of one cell at a time, get all the backgrounds at once by using [getBackgrounds](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackgrounds). Example:

```
/*
 * Return the backgrounds of the referenced cells.
 * 
 * @param {"A1:A5"} reference A reference string
 *
 * @customfunction
 */
function myBackgrounds(reference) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(reference);
  return range.getBackgrounds();
}
```